# Entity Framework 6 dynamically populate data without models

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm currently trying to read data from a table out of SQL server. The table has 10 columns and when i'm reading the base table by itself, everything works out just fine.

The trouble is, there are X number of extra property tables that may or may not go with my base table. Some databases only have the base table with 10 columns, while others have property tables containing more columns that must be joined into the base table in order to properly display the needed data. Is there a way via EF6 to load that data into a queryable source in a decoupled way?

Basically due to the fact that the extra tables are constantly in flux, I cannot rely on generating models for them and using the mapping EF provides. I do have a model for the base table as its 10 columns never change. I also have a mechanism to read the relational information in order to get the names of the property tables and columns that my program needs to display with the base table when they are available.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a partial EAV type of situation. Can you query the extra columns that are not always persistent as xml? Your question is pretty sparse on details.

Comment: EF needs a statically defined database schema. There's no way to make it flex to different db objects at runtime. Micro ORMs like Dapper are better in this respect. This also sounds like something that calls for a NoSQL solution.

Comment: If you can modify the data structure, then it sounds like you could model your columns as rows in an generic property table with a column 'Key' and 'Value'. Then you'd be able to use Entity Framework with no problems. But if the data structure is given (though it seems not to deserve the work structure ;-) ), then that won't help you I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Good old-fashioned ADO.NET does a good job giving you run-time access to arbitrary query results.  You can examine the column data types returned in a DataReader or after loaded into a DataTable, and access columns by name or ordinal position.

And you can interop beteween EF (for your design-time models) and ADO.NET tables that vary at runtime.